# React - Create Error Checking for Props in Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I'm creating a component and I want the value of a prop I'm passing to be an integer which is less than 10. What I want is if the prop is either not an integer or is greater or equal to 10 for an error to occur in React.

Example of how I want this to work:

```
export default function Component (props){
    typeof(props.number) != 'number' && // raise exception
    props.number >= 10 && // raise exception
}
```

Comment: You have the condition. put it in an if statement, and then throw in the if block.

Comment: Instead of the `typeof` check, use [`Number.isInteger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger). Other than that, as @evolutionxbox said, you have the check...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a more declarative approach, use "prop-types" [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) 
With this approach, you segregate validation logic from rendering itself.

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Component number={23} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Component(props) {
  return "Component rendered";
}

Component.propTypes = {
  number: function (props, propName) {
    if (typeof props[propName] !== "number" || props[propName] >= 10) {
      throw new Error("Invalid prop");
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Perfect! prop-types seems like exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Consider simply throwing an exception:

```js
export default function Component (props){
    if (typeof(props.number) != 'number' || props.number >= 10) {
        throw new TypeError("Invalid property number. Must be numeric and < 10.")
    }

    // Your other code here...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure if React had it's own error checking system I needed to use.